# CSS Box Is not being created

Tags: css, html

Here's the website that I'm working on: http://cinicraft.com/Silverman/index.html

and I'm trying to make some buttons but the **CSS** is having no effect.
This contract of mine was all going well until this happened, I literally want to make a simple box around each item in the "Inventory" section and nothing happens.

Here's the **HTML5** code:

```
<div class="btn1inv">
MACHINE SCREWS
</div>
```

And here's the **CSS** code:

```
/*Machine Screws*/
div.btn1inv
{
text-align:center;
background-color: #ff0404;
width:150px;
height:50px;
padding:1px;
margin:5px;
}
```

And NOTHING is happening to MACHINE SCREWS, despite the **CSS** code, the **HTML5** is deciding to ignore it and is not drawing a box. The `div` is just not working at all, what could be causing this problem? I picked the random ugly color since I'm just trying to get this **CSS** applied.

Comment: Seems to edit just fine if I add CSS in Chrome's inspector. It must be due to some cascading issue in your style sheet.

Comment: Try putting its style settings at the beginning of the CSS file and tell us what happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have error in your CSS file "style.css". Here is your problem above `div.btn1inv`:

```
.everything
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow-y:scroll;        
}â€‹ /* < delete this "â€‹" */

/*Machine Screws*/
div.btn1inv
{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ff0404;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    padding:1px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: lol thank you. This is weird but I cannot actually see that in my style.css file however when I try using the next one down called div.btn2inv and so on the problem is completely gone. Don't know how that weird thing got there but it does not show up on Coda 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. I use chrome to directly add inline css based on your file css, and it works.
2. I dived into the style.css, and interestingly I see a red dot in line 99, when using chrome to see the source. This line is just before the div.btn1inv line.

So, can you check if there is any illegal characters?

edit -- from Michal's post, there is a "â€‹" character.

Answer (score 0):

Run the css through the w3.org css validation tool. scroll to the last error element returned (which is the .btn1inv that you wish to style) - check out what the error is:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcinicraft.com%2FSilverman%2Findex.html

If there are tools for checking errors, it's always worth using them first. =)